# fullscreen & centred background image script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have made a simple function that adapts the size of an image according to the size of the window. I can't determine when exactly, but sometimes the img does not fill the width of the screen, but continues to stick to the height. Any idea why this could be?

If i console log (iRatio <= wRatio) anything seems to fit, but the shown result is incorrect.

The img is set as `postion: absolute; with: 100%; top:0; left:0;` in the css.
`$win` contains `$(window)` and `$img` the background image

```
function autoImageSize($img, $win){
        var wHeight = $win.height(),
            wWidth = $win.width(),
            iHeight = $img.height(),
            iWidth = $img.width(),
            iRatio = iWidth / iHeight, 
            wRatio = wWidth / wHeight;

          if(iRatio <= wRatio){
            $img.css({
               width: "100%", 
               height: "auto",
               top: "-" + ((iHeight - wHeight)/2) + "px",
               left: 0
            });
          }else{
            $img.css({
               width: "auto", 
               height: "100%",
               top: 0,
               left: "-" + ((iWidth - wWidth)/2) + "px"
             });
          }

          return [$img.width(), $img.height()];
};
```

Comment: I think you mean _...and `$img` the background image._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was:

```
left: "-" + ((iWidth - wWidth)/2) + "px"
```

and

```
top: "-" + ((iHeight - wHeight)/2) + "px"
```

this is a stupid way to do a negation, sometimes the result was --somenumber px. i fixed the problem by doing this operation only wen the iHeight is smaller then the wHeight oder the iWidth is smaller then wWidth and by calculating the negation with a multiplication by -1.

Answer (score -1):

When you are setting the image's width to 100% it will fill up to its parent's width. As is the case with the height of 100%, but there the parent also needs a fixed height in pixels (as far as I know).

Instead of setting the height to 100% you should calculate the width matching the height of the window using the image's ratio:

```
var toWidth = $win.height() * iRatio;
$img.width(toWidth);
```

Comment: Please provide some feedback when voting down.

Comment: this does not solve the problem. The paret is a div in position fixed that has top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom: 0; but anyway the downvote is not from me.

Comment: If I get this right, your image will sometimes not stretch to the full width or height of its parent and cover the whole window? `height: 100%` needs the parent element to have a fixed height in pixels, namely the windows height. Am I getting it wrong?

Comment: no sometimes it does not strech to the full width. You get something wrong. When you set a div as postion fixed and and top, right, bottom and left to 0 it fills the screen. No matter what the parent element is. The image is inside this div.

Comment: I did not know that! You might want to add that to your question. Can you provide a demonstration of you problem? Is the ratio intact or is it stretched vertically?

Comment: i could, but i found the problem. And this changes nothing to the actual problem. I postet the awnser myself